# Error while creating basic IBM Blockchain network on the IBM Container Service's free plan

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I have created the setup from https://ibm-blockchain.github.io  to launch a basic IBM Blockchain network on the IBM Container Service's free plan.

Now once setup is complete, when I am trying to deploy new network from composer, getting following error

Error: Error trying to start business network. Error: No valid responses from any peers. Response from attempted peer comms was an error: Error: 2 UNKNOWN: error starting container: Failed to generate platform-specific docker build: Error returned from build: 1 "npm ERR! code ENOTFOUND npm ERR! errno ENOTFOUND npm ERR! network request to https://registry.npmjs.org/composer-common failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND registry.npmjs.org registry.npmjs.org:443 npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity. npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings. npm ERR! network npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly. See: 'npm help config' npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR! /root/.npm/_logs/2018-10-06T05_50_16_478Z-debug.log "

What went wrong here?

Environment - Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: As well as the answer below, you can also take a look at  https://github.com/IBM-Blockchain/ibm-container-service/issues/119

Answer (score 1):

The Kubernetes Cluster Service on IBM Cloud has been upgraded and no longer supports Composer.  The documentation is undergoing modifications to reflect this.

Your options are to run a Development Fabric locally on your own infrastructure, or move to IBM Blockchain Starter Plan.